# Can't check if int is null

Tags: java, dictionary, null

I'm trying to use a dictionary. Whenever I want to check if an element is present in the dictionary, I do this:

```
int value = results.get("aKeyThatMayOrMayNotBePresent");

if (value != null)
  // ...
```

But then the compiler says I can't compare an `int` to a `<nulltype>`. What's the correct way to check for `null` in this case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're comparing a primitive value (int) to null. Since primitives cannot be null, you should use a corresponding object, such as Integer in this case. So, you should write

```
Integer value = results.get("aKeyThatMayOrMayNotBePresent");
```

Answer (score 18):

Your null check is too late.

```
int value = results.get("aKeyThatMayOrMayNotBePresent");
```

This line already converts the reference to a primitive `int`. It will throw a NullPointerException if the return value of get is null.

The correct way would be to use `Integer` instead of `int`.

```
Integer value = results.get("aKeyThatMayOrMayNotBePresent");
```

This way value wont be a primitive type and your null check is valid.

Answer (score 2):

int is a primitive type; you can compare a `java.lang.Integer` to null.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `Object` and check if that is null.

```
Object valueObj = results.get("...");
if ( valueObj != null )
{
    Integer value = (Integer)valueObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of [`Dictionary`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html), `Dictionary` is obsolete.

With `Map` you can use [`containsKey()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) instead, which in my opinion is more readable:

```
if (results.containsKey(key))
{
    int value = results.get(key);
    [...]
}
```

In my experience this is not slower than your approach, despite the apparent double access to the map.  If this is executed often enough for performance to matter then it is optimized away.