# Android Studio not giving warning under certain conditions

Tags: android, android-studio

Please excuse the slightly odd question, but I'm unsure if this is a bug in Android studio, my understanding or something I've setup wrong. My minimum API is set to 16. [densityDpi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#densityDpi) was introduced to Configuration in API 17.

This code produces an Android studio requires API warning:

```
int test = getResources().getConfiguration().densityDpi;
```

So does this:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
int test = config.densityDpi
```

But this does not

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
if(config.densityDpi == 1){
    int test = 1;
}
```

The fact it doesn't produce a warning means it was missed and caused a crash in all Android versions less than 17.

Does anyone have any idea why Android Studio is not warning for this?

Comment: It might be because the last case is not an assignment, but a comparison. Compiler might not check required API on a variable that is not "used"

Comment: could show such warnings?

Comment: You might want to file a bug report in the official issue tracker. To me, it seems irrelevant *why* it doesn't warn, what matters is that it doesn't warn where it should.

Comment: If you add a null check on the last example does it avoid the crash in previous versions ?

Comment: @hellyale good suggestion, but densityDpi is an int, can't do a null check on an int.

Comment: @James http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059057/cant-check-if-int-is-null

Comment: I've added a bug, will see what they say:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=262392&thanks=262392&ts=1490272390